# sqlcontext not accepting port number

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

, 
I have two codes, that intend to connect to a database,and throw the table content on screen.

## first code

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._


val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("tets_HIVE4").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory","1g").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
var props = new java.util.Properties()
props.setProperty("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
 val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP:port;databaseName=db_name;user=uid;password=pwd","dbtable" -> "tbl_name")).load()

jdbcDF.show(5)
exit()
```

## second code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._
import java.util.Properties

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP/db_name:port").option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").option("dbtable","tbl_name").option("user","uid").option("password","uid").load()

df.show(5)
exit()
```

1st code is working fine, but the 2nd code ain't.for the 2nd code , I am getting  following error:;

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host server_IP/db_name port "port-num" has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I am pretty sure that the port number is correct, as the 1st code has the same port, and its working. So, that brings me to a conclusion that I am making some syntactical error in my 2nd code.I tried to put the port number as .option("port","port_num"), but didn't work. Then I tried mentioning port as .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP/db_name:port"), even this doesn't work.

So, I have following questions::

1)what is the basic difference between the two code apart from the syntax placement?when should we use each one of them and what situation?

2)what would be the right syntax in 2nd code to mention port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `db_name` in 2 very different places, and according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx the second is illegal. Try `.option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP:port").option("databaseName", "db_name")`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It was the only thing that I needed.We can close the thread

Comment: @user3521180 You don't need to "close the thread" on Stack Overflow, accepting the answer (which you already did) is enough.